# ElasticSearch not sorting results

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to sort the results based on a `numeric` field,

Here is my mapping:

```
{
  "elasticie": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "number": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Python, and this is my testing data:

```py
data = [
    {'name': 'sElwUYiLXGHaQCKbdxtnvVzqIehfFWkJcPSTurgNoRD', 'number': 8583},
    {'name': 'XJEtNsIFfcwHTMhqAvRkiygjbUGzZQPdS', 'number': 8127},
    {'name': 'ZIeAGosUKJbjOdylM', 'number': 5862},
    {'name': 'HYvcafoXkC', 'number': 7458},
    {'name': 'tATJCjNuizOlGckXBpyVqSQL', 'number': 530},
    {'name': 'TFYixotjhXzNZPvHnkraRDpAMEImJfqdcVGLC', 'number': 7052},
    {'name': 'JCEGfoKDHRrcIkPQSqiVgNshZOBaMdXjAlxwUzmeWLy', 'number': 6168},
    {'name': 'IpCTwUAQynSizJtcsuDmbX', 'number': 6492},
    {'name': 'fTrcoXSBJNFhAkzWpDMxsEiLmZRvgnC', 'number': 382},
    {'name': 'ulVNmqKTpPXfEIdiykhDjMrUGOYazLBFvgnWwsRtJoQbxSe', 'number': 2061}
]
```

Using following code, I'm creating the index and inserting the data:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from data import data  # the data I've shown above

INDEX = 'elasticie'
es = Elasticsearch('http://127.0.0.1:9200')

for _ in data:
    es.index(index=INDEX, body=_)
```

I'm trying to sort data based on number, `asc` or `desc`
Here is what I tried so far:

```
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number': {'order': 'asc'}})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number': 'asc'})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': [('number', 'asc')]})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number': {'order': 'asc', 'ignore_unmapped': True}})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'integer'}})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'long'}})
es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': {'number.raw': 'asc'})
```

Not of the above methods worked for me, The result is the same as the inserted data,
If I assign the above lines to a variable named `search_result` and print the result using the following code:

```
for index, result in enumerate(search_result['hits']['hits']):
    print(f'{index}. {result["_source"]["number"]}')
```

I'll get the following result:

```
0. 8583
1. 8127
2. 5862
3. 7458
4. 530
5. 7052
6. 6168
7. 6492
8. 382
9. 2061
```

Which is obviously not sorted using `number` field!!

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm using ElasticSearch 7.6 and Python 3.8

How can I make the sorting results work?

**Update**

Based on debugging logs, Python is sending a `GET` request to the following URL using the first method:
`http://127.0.0.1:9200/elasticie/_search?sort={%27number%27%3A+{%27order%27%3A+%27asc%27}}`

Comment: Could you provide your search JSON, I tried with your dataset and it worked very well with my search query, I don't have `pyhton` setup but can share my postman collection, if you want to try out these API yourself

Comment: You should try with this request : `es.search(index=INDEX, params={'sort': [{'number': {'order': 'asc'}}]})`

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Added the request information to the question

Comment: @fmdaboville Already tried that, getting the same result as before

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, why you are sending `sort` param as a query param and making `GET` request, can you change it to `POST` and send `sort` param as part of your body

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, also I just decoded your url param and its translating to `{'number':+{'order':+'asc'}}` which is giving me `illegal_argument_exception` when I hit it using postman, as `sort` option is missing

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, strane, Even with `GET`, you can pass the `search body` and it gives me proper results

Comment: @fmdaboville, wanted to point out the same, but then realised he already tried that

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja You're comment led me to the answer, It works well on the POST request, I was doing the search using what the python library's doc string was telling me to do, I read the docs again, seems like it takes a `sort` argument which makes the library send the request using `POST` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209298/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-darksunium).

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I just add the '[' which seems to be missing on each tries.
@DarkSuniuM The elastic doc make it work with a `GET` with a search https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#search-request-sort

Comment: @fmdabovillem I know it works well, with the `GET` and thats what I mentioned in previous comment but it's not recommended to send the search payload as part of your query string(has a lot of known issues), best to use the post method, which also solved the OP problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I read the documentation and the code functionality using `help` and `dir` functions

There is no parameter named `sort` defined on the `Elasticsearch.search` method, That's why I thought I should use it as a `key` within the `params` dict that it takes,

Thanks to [@OpsterElasticSearchNinja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039431/opster-elasticsearch-ninja) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598395/elasticsearch-not-sorting-results?noredirect=1#comment107208428_60598395), I realized there is something wrong with either the library or how I'm using it

Sending POST request with `sort` key as post body worked well,
So I decided to read the whole source code and find out what's going wrong?

```
@query_params(
    #...
    "size",
    "sort",
    #...
)
def search(self, body=None, index=None, doc_type=None, params=None):
    # ...
```

This is how the `sort` parameter is defined, using a decorator on runtime!!

That's when I tried this code, and somehow it worked!

```
es.search(index=INDEX, sort=['number:asc'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `python`, but here is the Elasticsearch JSON query which would sort your documents according to the numbers in `desc` order. I've tried with your data set and it gives proper results.

### Sort Search query

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "number": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Results

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "so-60598395-sort",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "name": "sElwUYiLXGHaQCKbdxtnvVzqIehfFWkJcPSTurgNoRD",
               "number": 8583
            },
            "sort": [
               8583
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60598395-sort",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "name": "XJEtNsIFfcwHTMhqAvRkiygjbUGzZQPdS",
               "number": 8127
            },
            "sort": [
               8127
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60598395-sort",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "name": "HYvcafoXkC",
               "number": 7862
            },
            "sort": [
               7862
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "so-60598395-sort",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "name": "ZIeAGosUKJbjOdylM",
               "number": 5862
            },
            "sort": [
               5862
            ]
         }
```

**EDIT:- Based on the OP comments, `python` library which he is using supports the POST method of search endpoint, using which he solved the issue. Refer to the comments on the question for more details.**